# Providing docker swarm container with host's public IP address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

### Problem:

I am trying to deploy a global node-exporter service on a swarm cluster using a docker-compose file and I need to have access to the nodes' actual IP address to be used as a label. My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
...
    environment:
      - NODE_ID={{.Node.ID}}
    volumes:
      - /etc/hostname:/etc/nodename
...
```

`{{.Node.ID}}` provides me with the ID as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates).

### What I tried:

By mounting `/etc/hostname` to the container, I can get the hostname, still, I could not find a directory that stores `ifconfig eth0` IPV4 on Ubuntu 18.04 to do the same for IP. I also checked if there is a template like `{{.Node.ID}}` to be used in the compose file to no avail.

### Question:

Is there any way to request docker engine to supply the container with the node's IP prior to deploying the container?